# Streaming MJPEG using UVC camera from USB camera from ARM using UDP to X86

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, frame-rate, mjpeg, usb-camera

I am using to use i.Mx6 Dual processor connected with USB Camera(UVC Camera) supporting 1080p 30FPS to Stream to X86 plaftform using UDP port.

1. I want to achieve streaming using 1080p with minimum latency.
2. I want to use MJPEG from i.MX6 to X86 without using any additional encodin/decoding, To verify that camera actually support 30FPS using 1080p.

Can any one help me using how I can achieve this.

**For streaming 1080p I am using below pipeline**

**Sender:** *gst-launch-1.0  v4l2src  device=/dev/video0  !  image/jpeg, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! jpegdec ! videoscale ! videoconvert  ! queue !
imxvpuenc_h264  bitrate=6000 gop-size=60 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.108 port=5000  sync=false*

**Receiver:** *gst-launch-1.0 -vc udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink  sync=false async=false*

**How to calculate the output frames for UVC camer to make it stream MJPEG from i.MX6 to X86 without using any additional encodin/decoding.
**

Answer (score 0):

If your camera is MJPG, you don't need to decode and encode into H264. H264 uses temporal redundancy using P and B frames, so this would increase latency as compared to MJPG where each frame can be encoded alone.

**Sender:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! rtpjpegpay ! queue ! udpsink host=192.168.0.108 port=5000
```

**Receiver:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,clock-rate=90000,payload=26 ! queue ! rtpjpegdepay ! decodebin ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=fakesink text-overlay=0 -v
```

Comment: Hello @SeB,

I tried using the above commands, I do not get any thing displayed on receiver.
I have added verbos at receiver and collected the logs.

Verbos Logs from receiver:
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, clock-rate=(int)90000, payload=(int)26, media=(string)video 
...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGDepay:rtpjpegdepay0.GstPad:src: caps = image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)0/1, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080

Comment: You may try adding jpegparse before rtpjpegpay on sender, and after rtpjpegdepay in receiver.

Comment: Small note: H264 *can* use P and B frames but that is configurable.
B frames are usually not used in real-time applications.